# Forward slash in a Slim classname?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

Anyone knows how to make a classname such as `.w-1/3` work in Slim? In regular css to use a forward slash in a class name it needs to be escaped: `w-1\/3` but this does not work in Slim.

Comment: "does not work" - what error do you get?

Comment: Right, Slim::Parser::SyntaxError of course

Comment: I think there is only one way for it: `div class="w-1/3"`

Comment: @Vasilisa care to write an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slim doesn't support forward slashes in class names.
I think there is the only one way for it: `div class="w-1/3"`